# Why is it truncate table, and not simply truncate?

Tags: sql-server, syntax, truncate

Upon reviewing some of our code a colleague posited that he was annoyed at always having to write `TRUNCATE TABLE` when there is no real other usage for `TRUNCATE`.

Googling this, I indeed can not find a specific reason why the `TABLE` part is needed.
What am I missing? Is there some historical reason for the `TABLE` in `TRUNCATE TABLE`?

Comment: It's probably because SQL is supposed to look like text. On the other hand I'd like to have a `TRUNCATE PARTITION/FILEGROUP/DATABASE` feature. It's an extensibility point for the language.

Comment: @usr the first one is possible in 2016 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177570(v=sql.130).aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The syntax choice is likely for consistency, albeit redundant.  `TRUNCATE TABLE` follows the same pattern as other DDL statements (CREATE, ALTER, DROP), where the object type immediately follows the action keyword.

I should add `TRUNCATE TABLE` is part of the ANSI SQL Standard as of the 2008 version, although it was implemented in SQL Server long before then.

Answer (score 3):

Seems to me its redundancy for future extensibility.  There may not be any other use for `TRUNCATE` currently, but one could be added in the future. Or at least that would have been the mindset of the developers.